# Hide state driven text until state is ready

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my application, I have different  components driven by the current text in state. E.g.:

```
<Text>Account Balance: {this.state.account_balance}</Text>
```

However, wondering what is best practice to only show these once the state is set (currently waiting on an axios call)?

My hacky solution is to set a 'show' state that controls some logic. But this feels long winded and suspect their may be more simple ways to handle this.

Comment: Do you need to hide it or are you able to just display an iterm value? Something simple like: <Text>Account Balance: {this.state.account_balance || 'Loading: Please wait'}</Text>

Comment: Thanks, thats a cool solution. Didnt know about that. Ideally tho would like to hide it outright

Comment: Assuming Text is a component you can add a isHidden property to the component state. <Text isHidden={this.state.account_balance == null}>Account Balance: {this.state.account_balance}</Text>

Comment: Thanks, thats a great middle ground - didnt know there was an isHidden property. Please post it as an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the account balance starts off as something like null to indicate it's not loaded yet, you can simply check for that before you render the `<Text>` element. For example:

```
state = {
  account_balance: null,
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch('someUrl');
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    account_balance: data
  });
}

render () {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.account_balance !== null && 
        <Text>Account Balance: {this.state.account_balance}</Text>
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a better solution than passing to the component if it should show.